# Iam getting an error when building the ionic app or running it live

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

ionic [cordova] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. on ionic cordova run android -l

I tried everything, still i cant solve this error[image: this is the error iam getting when i do ionic cordova run android -l]

Comment: Please dont post errors as photos. its better to copy and paste it here.

Comment: Ohk sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current error which is androidx:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

So these two will allow androidX to be enabled in your project, plus with these 2, you'll get better library support and thus better performance plus working on all android sdk platforms including 29+.